# Getting original ServiceStack route from DTO generated for TypeScript client

Tags: validation, servicestack, openapi

We had an issue in a production release where we get JSON response that differs from expected model described in a generated TypeScript DTO, while getting successful status code.

In our case, as a solution, we want to validate JSON response with use of JSON schema metadata provided as a part of OpenAPI document by supported `OpenApiFeature` (usually `/openapi` endpoint). Document contains required response metadata on the following path:

```js
openapi.paths[Route][HttpMethod].respones[StatusCode].schema
```

There are three variables that we want to get at runtime:

- HTTP Method - this one specified explicitly
- HTTP Respose Status Code - this can be fetched as last status code from `client.responseFilter`
- Route Path - **this one is the problem**

As an example let's use following DTO:

```cs
[Route("/api20/data", "GET")]
public class GetData20 : IReturns<Data>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Usual way to make request using `JsonServiceClient`:

```js
const data = await client.get(new GetData20({ id }));
```

We want to get original route, as described in `RouteAttribute`, associated with the HTTP request that will be made.

Diving into `JsonServiceClient` implementation shows that there are no API for getting the route. Client itself relies on `/json/reply/nameof(TResponse)` route, where `nameof(TResponse)` is a DTO constructor function name.

Generated DTOs file contains the route only as a comment in a JS decorator format. If it is possible to enable some feature to make this a real decorator, that will extend resulting object with a route data - it would be an one of possible solutions.

.NET `TypeScriptGenerator` allows us to add any TypeScript code for generated DTOs - this also can be used as a solution.

As an obvious solution we can specify route for every request along with request DTO, but we'd prefer more generic way if it's possible.

What will be considered as a best practice to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The route information is not accessible programmatically from the generated DTOs, you would need to resolve it from API metadata which you could resolve from your App Metadata from `/metadata/app.json`, e.g:

- https://northwind.netcore.io/metadata/app.json

Which is available from `/api/operations[op]/routes`

If you have `OpenApiFeature` enabled you could resolve it from the `/openapi` json endpoint, e.g:

- https://todos.netcore.io/openapi

You could parse the Route information embedded in comments in `/types/typescript` which is annotated on each Request DTO, e.g:

```js
// @Route("/orders")
// @Route("/orders/page/{Page}")
// @Route("/customers/{CustomerId}/orders", "GET")
export class GetOrders implements IReturn<OrdersResponse>, IGet
{
    public page?: number;
    public customerId: string;

    public constructor(init?: Partial<GetOrders>) { (Object as any).assign(this, init); }
    public getTypeName() { return 'GetOrders'; }
    public getMethod() { return 'GET'; }
    public createResponse() { return new OrdersResponse(); }
}
```

Effectively by scanning for `// @Route`, parsing the route information that's associated with the subsequent Request DTO in `export class <RequestDTO>`.

Otherwise you can return a custom API with the information in the format you want, populated from the API metadata maintained internally in `HostContext.Metadata`.

Comment: `OpenApiFeature` - is the source of information we want to use. But first we need to map our request to the OpenAPI document, so we need the original path. Usual way to send requests using ServiceStack `JsonServiceClient` is like that: `client.get(new GetData20())`. Our concern is to get original route for this call.

I can't find out how to use suggested way to parse `/metadata/app.json` - can you explain this?

Comment: You need to traverse the metadata document, the route information is maintained in `/api/operations[op]/routes`, otherwise return a custom API in the format you want it in.

Comment: I've made minor edit to the question with additional information from above comment. Just to clarify: there is no implemented way to get direct mapping from the JS `JsonServiceClient` calls with generated DTOs to routes defined in the ServiceStack server application which also described in the OpenAPI document?

Comment: @PavelMikheev I've explained that it's not available from generated DTOs and listed different ways to access the route information, which part of my answer is unclear?

Comment: I'd suggest to extend OpenAPI document provided by the `OpenApiFeature` with pre-defined routes, to have all required information described. From my point of view, to provide all the required metadata for all public routes in OpenAPI document - can be considered as correct behavior for the server.

Comment: predefined routes accept every verb, via QueryString/FormData, posted body, in all supported content-type formats, attempting to include them would explode the size of the openapi schema, rendering it worthless.

Comment: I see, extending OpenAPI document it's also not an option. As of DTOs can have multiple bound routes we also can't guess final endpoint from any metadata, while using `JsonServiceClient` methods which relies on pre-defined endpoints based on DTO constructor function name. Thus only robust way here to use explicit API calls to well-known endpoints, right?

Comment: If your goal is to only call API endpoints defined in /openapi - you would either only call hard-coded user defined routes or extend/generate a new openapi spec with all the endpoints your App ends up using.